# More than one singleton instance in Guice injector

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

We got a Jetty/Jersey application. We are converting it to use Guice for DI. The problem: We need more than one instance of a Singleton classes. The catch: The number of instances is determined dynamically from a configuration file. Therefore we cant use annotations for different instances.

```
 final InjectedClass instance = injector.getInstance(InjectedClass.class);
```

This is the standard syntax of the injector. I need something like

```
 final String key = getKey();
 final InjectedClass instance = injector.getInstance(InjectedClass.class, key);
```

There is a way to get an instance from a Guice `Key.class`

```
 final InjectedClass instance = injector.getInstance(Key.get(InjectedClass.class, <Annotation>);
```

but the problem is that I need some dynamic annotation, not predefined one.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use Provider, or @Provides method that would have map of all instances already created. When the number of instances is reached number defained in config file, you wont create any new instances, instead  you return old instance from map.

For example something like this could help you.

```
public class MyObjectProvider implements Provider<MyObject> {
  private final Injector inj;
  private int counter;
  private final int maxNum = 5;
  private List<MyObject> myObjPool = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

  @Inject
  public MyObjectProvider(Injector inj) {
    this.connection = connection;
  }

  public MyObject get() {
    counter = counter+1%maxNum;
    if(myObjPool.size()=<maxNum) {
      MyObject myobj = inj.getInstance(MyObject.class);
      myObjPool.add(myobj);
      return myobj;
    } else {
       return myObjPool.get(counter);
    }
  }
}
```

P.S. 
I wrote this from my head so maybe it does not compile, this is just an idea.

Comment: Thanks. You are suggesting an InstancePool, which is not the solution. I need map of instances, because there are difference between instances, every time I need to inject a specific instance I need that particular instance, not random. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @fiction: Please edit you question so that this requirement is included.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by creating a factory. In my example I have used the guice extension called [multibindings](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Multibindings)

```
interface InjectedClassFactory {
    public InjectedClass get(String key);
}

class InjectedClass {}

class InjectedClassFactoryImpl implements InjectedClassFactory{
    private final Map<String, InjectedClass> instances;

    @Inject
    InjectedClassFactoryImpl(Map<String, InjectedClass> instances) {
        this.instances = instances;
    }

    @Override
    public InjectedClass get(String key) {
        return instances.get(key);
    }
}

class MyModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        MapBinder<String, InjectedClass> mapBinder =
                MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), String.class, InjectedClass.class);

        //read you config file and retrieve the keys
        mapBinder.addBinding("key1").to(InjectedClass.class).in(Singleton.class);
        mapBinder.addBinding("key2").to(InjectedClass.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}
```